# How to reshape an array of points into an image

Tags: python, point, image, numpy

I have a numpy array of shape (1964, 3), in the following format:

[
   [ 0.3945, 52.700, 0.8 ],
   [ 0.3788, 52.121, 0.3 ]
]
etc.

Each nested array represents a point in the format of [longitude, latitude, value]

I am trying to do a points.reshape() in order to convert this array into an image however am unable to calculate the columns and rows for the image.

It might be that I'm missing something incredibly simple here but can anyone suggest a solution to this issue?

I also have a pickle file of the array I'm working with so I'm happy to send if anyone wants.

Comment: Which GIS software are you using?

Comment: @BERA I am trying to solve all of this in Python

Comment: With which libraries?

Comment: I've been using only numpy currently but I am open to any suggestions